# I am getting `userCoins.get is not a function` error when `anchor-earn` tries to get the balance of a wallet

Tags: javascript, web3js

When using `AnchorEarn` from the `@anchor-protocol/anchor-earn` module to get a balance

```
import { AnchorEarn } from '@anchor-protocol/anchor-earn'


const userBalance = await anchorEarn.balance({
            currencies: [DENOMS.UST],
        });
```

I am getting the following error:

```
userCoins.get is not a function
```

I am using the following script to install it `npm i @anchor-protocol/anchor-earn` and I am following the sample script in Anchor's website, any idea of what could be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line to install `anchor-earn`:

```
npm install -S @anchor-protocol/anchor-earn@2.0.0-alpha1
```

Comment: For context: https://github.com/Anchor-Protocol/anchor-earn/issues/24